# How to deal with Google Console release declaration form for SMS/Call Log

Tags: google-play-console

We are trying to submit a release update on the GooglePlay store.  We are being forced to select an option for SMS/Call Log exception declaration when we don't use the permissions in our app and they aren't in our manifest.  it appears there is a radio button that hides a question that, if we answer yes, it would remove this form, but the radio buttons are not visible on the page (only able to see after messing with the HTML code).

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly when this happens for a user it is for one of two reasons:

- they have another old version which asks for SMS / Call log permissions on an alpha or beta or testing track that they have forgotten about. Solution: remove the old alpha / beta version before publishing the new version
- they do require SMS or call log permissions, but don't realize it. Normally this is because they are using a third part library in their build that requires this permission. This can be easily checked, try reading [this medium post](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/how-libraries-can-silently-add-permissions-to-your-android-app-620911d7de6c)